# Alarm service Not stopping or starts improper

Tags: android, android-service

i m really fed up with the alarm service that i m created. i created an alarm service for showing an alert in my application at 8 am, 4 pm , 12 am of each day in my application. It works fine and alert showing perfectly. i'm canceling my service when closing the app, but some times the alert comes without meeting the time such as after exit the app, when removing the app from tab history, when takes the settings of the device, i'm not getting why this happens, i was checking for a solution in SO but didnt get any proper solution please help me
here giving my code.

```
 public void StartService()
{
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    dfcurrent = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy");
    long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    currentdate = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());
    String currentdate1 = dfcurrent.format(currentdate);

    Long datetoalert1 = Utility.DateReturn(currentdate1+" - "+08:00AM);
    if(datetoalert1 < currentTime)
    {
        Date d = new Date(datetoalert1);
        c.setTime(d);
        c.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
        d = c.getTime();
        datetoalert1 = d.getTime();

    }

    Long datetoalert2 = Utility.DateReturn(currentdate1+" - "+04:00PM);

    if(datetoalert2 < currentTime)
    {
        Date d = new Date(datetoalert2);
        c.setTime(d);
        c.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
        d = c.getTime();
        datetoalert2 = d.getTime();

    }

    Long datetoalert3 = Utility.DateReturn(currentdate1+" - "+00:00AM);

    if(datetoalert3 < currentTime)
    {
        Date d = new Date(datetoalert3);
        c.setTime(d);
        c.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
        d = c.getTime();
        datetoalert3 = d.getTime();

    }

    Intent myIntent1 = new Intent(Login.this, MyReceiver.class);

    pendingIntentSApp1 = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(Login.this, 7, myIntent1,0);
    pendingIntentSApp2 = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(Login.this, 8, myIntent1,0);
    pendingIntentSApp3 = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(Login.this, 9, myIntent1,0);

   AlarmManager alarmManager1 = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
   AlarmManager alarmManager2 = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
   AlarmManager alarmManager3 = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);

   alarmManager1.set(AlarmManager.RTC, datetoalert1, pendingIntentSApp1);
   alarmManager2.set(AlarmManager.RTC, datetoalert2, pendingIntentSApp2);
   alarmManager3.set(AlarmManager.RTC, datetoalert3, pendingIntentSApp3);
}
```

i m cancelling this pending intent when closing the app. here giving the code

```
  public void exit_btn_click(View view)
{

    Intent myIntent1 = new Intent(Login.this, MyReceiver.class);
    pendingIntentSApp1 = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(Login.this, 7, myIntent1,0);
    pendingIntentSApp2 = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(Login.this, 8, myIntent1,0);
    pendingIntentSApp3 = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(Login.this, 9, myIntent1,0);

     AlarmManager alarmManager1 = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
     AlarmManager alarmManager2 = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
     AlarmManager alarmManager3 = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
     alarmManager1.cancel(pendingIntentSApp1);
     alarmManager2.cancel(pendingIntentSApp2);
      alarmManager3.cancel(pendingIntentSApp3);


    System.exit(0);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

first of all you should not do this:

```
 AlarmManager alarmManager1 = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
 AlarmManager alarmManager2 = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
 AlarmManager alarmManager3 = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
```

enough only one link to alarmManager.

Also try to remove
System.exit(0);
call

Answer (score 1):

try to add flag to the pending intent

```
pendingIntentSApp1 = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(Login.this, 7, myIntent1,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

or better alarm id

Answer (score 0):

You will have to cancel the PendingIntent as well after you cancel the alarm.

```
          try {
             alarmManagerstop.cancel(getSendLocationIntent(context, 0));
            getSendLocationIntent(context, 0).cancel();
            } catch (Exception e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
              }
```

This will fix your problem.